# Ionic pinch to zoom in image

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I just want to put an image in an ion-view make it full width and allow zoomIn/ zoomOut on pinch event. It looks easy but I could make it!! I am new in Ionic1. can someone help me?

This what I tried but couldn't achieve what I want:

`<ion-view view-title="MAP">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" delegate-handle="zoom-pane"         class="zoom-pane" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false">
            <img ng-src="img/map.png">
        </ion-scroll>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>`

Answer (score 6):

Just you have to add overflow-scroll="false" property in ion-scroll

HTML

```
        <ion-scroll id="mapImage"
                zooming="true"
                direction="xy"
                delegate-handle="zoom-pane"
                class="zoom-pane"
                min-zoom="1"
                max-zoom="15"
                overflow-scroll="false">
            <img ng-src="img/map.png">
    </ion-scroll>
```

CSS

```
.zoom-pane {
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
}

.zoom-pane .scroll {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;    
}

.zoom-pane img {
    width: 100% !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

Comment: Great solution bro, saved my day, Thanks a lot.